# Speed up window.setTimeout in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, settimeout, puppeteer

I'm loading a web app that makes use of various long timeouts, in puppeteer, and would like to skip all these timeouts. How do I make every call to `setTimeout` from the webpage return quickly, no matter the delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `setTimeout` in [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args):

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window._real_setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
    window.setTimeout = (func, delay, ...args) => {
        return window._real_setTimeout(func, 10, ...args);
    };
});
```

You can also do a similar version for `setInterval`, if your web application uses it. Note that this seems to mess with puppeteer's `page.waitForFunction` (it gets executed only once), so you may need to restore the real functionality with

```
window.setTimeout = window._real_setTimeout;
```

if you want the real behavior.